# Hot Shot Feat of Strength

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I see everywhere that the Hot Shot Feat of Strength can be unlocked by winning 5 placement matches. I've did this with a friend in 2v2, but none of us got the achievement.

Can anyone confirm that it does exist?

Comment: It's broken.  It does exist, but it is broken.  I once got it after going 4-1 on placement matches.  I've heard a lot of people complain it was just broken and awarded randomly.  And that is what happened with me.  It's there.  It just randomly decides to award itself improperly.

Answer (score 1):

It exists. As of Patch 1.1, it is now attainable.

There are trigger components in the editor to award it (though obviously, nothing accessible through the editor involves actually awarding it, and the awarding of achievements on custom maps is impossible at any rate).

A better question might be: "Why didn't I receive this feat of strength?" to which I don't know. <strike>It's possible it's reserved for 1v1 placements, only checks the first set of placement matches per season,</strike> or **something else entirely**.

Comment: "It's possible it's reserved for 1v1 placements, only checks the first set of placement matches per season, or something else entirely." Both of those have been confirmed as incorrect for earning this feat of strength.

Comment: I have won all 5 of my placement matches for 1v1 and the first two matches after being placed in Platinum 1v1 and was not awarded the achievement.

Answer (score 1):

I got this achievement in the middle of the fifth game for 4v4 placement. I was already 2 wins and 2 loses, so it isn't for 5 wins. It happend during intensive micro during battle, so I didn't notice what achievement I got until I finished the game. In the end we lost even the fifth game. Sorry, nothing special comes to mind, that could trigger such an achievemt.

**EDIT**: I checked the replays and I actually went 3 wins 2 losses and in the middle of the 6th game I got the achievement. It might be that the achievement is just bugged. Or it really needs a different trigger than 5-0 in placement matches.

Comment: It was impossible to obtain this achievement before patch 1.1, which was when the question was originally asked.

Answer (score 1):

It is attainable, but I think it may be buggy.

I won all my random 2v2 placements, and to my disappointment, I was not awarded this achievement. A few weeks later, I did random 4v4, and after winning all placements on that, I did finally receive it.

Answer (score -1):

While theoretically this achievement exists, and has a nice description. It has not been earned. People are thinking that it might be for tournament play, and not for ladder play.

Comment: So you're saying no one ever got it?

Comment: @eric As far as the experts have determined, no one has actually gotten it for winning 5 in a row placement matches.

Comment: I got it for winning 5 in a row of placement matches