# What are the requirements for the Hot Shot feat of strength?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

So, I got awarded the "Hot Shot" feat of strength and I would like to know what I have done to earn it.

The only thing I can find about it is people saying you have to win all 5 placement matches and that this is the "qualification round" that the description refers to.

For no type of league have I finished my placement matches 5-0, so that can't be the requirement. I played my last placement match roughly a week ago and all my placement matches have been pretty mediocre. With several days passed between the last placement matches and getting awarded the achievement, this connection seems unlikely altogether...

So, what earns you this achievement?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6563/hot-shot-feat-of-strength

Answer (score 3):

Congradulations. Achievement is granted after going 5-0 (5 wins, 0 losses) in a qualification round. It was only not turn on before patch 1.1.0  so people that tried this before patch 1.1 did not get it.

Both you and I experienced a bug. There is a recognized bug to get the Hot Shot achievement after the recent 1.01 patch release without accomplishing 5-0, however.

Comment: and the bug is...?